# As a beginner how can start learning Appium tool as a Mobile testing?

Tags: appium, mobile, mobile-automation, learning, mobile-applications

From where should I start learning `Appium - mobile testing`.

My current organization has an framework, which used an `Appium to run Script on Mobile devices`?

What are the challenges do I need to overcome while learning `Appium`?

FYI: I'm `Selenium` guy who knows `Java` basics.

Comment: https://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-tutorial/
http://learn-automation.com/appium-tutorial-for-beginners/ Know your requirement then start step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in your situation when I have good command over selenium but want to learn Mobile automation. I have checked multiple blogs and video tutorials. I found the below blog is really helpful and provide step by step guide.

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/category/appium/

Just cross check all article from beginning. You will feel it really helpful.

Comment: @rocky I am glad to help you.